# django filter based on field/column values

Tags: django

I have a model ModelA.

```
class ModelA:
    m2m_1_field = models.BooleanField()
    #lots of other fields
```

It has 2 m2m relations m2m_1 and m2m_2 both returning the same type.
If field m2m_1_field of ModelA is True, then we need to get the m2m results from m2m_1 (like instance.m2m_1.all()).
If field m2m_1_field of ModelA is False, then we need to get the m2m results from m2m_2 (Like instance.m2m_2.all()).

So, while searching this model, I also have to search these m2m relations.

Lets say, we need to search for m2m objects with ids 1 and 2.  Then, we should do this:

```
if m2m_1_field is True:
    for id in [1,2]:
        queryset = queryset.filter(m2m_1__id=id)
if m2m_1_field is False:
    for id in [1,2]:
        queryset = queryset.filter(m2m_2__id=id)
```

Above is just theoritical explanation, how can we do it practically?

Or simply forget about m2m, just assume there are 2 more fields f1, f2 (both char fields). If m2m_1_field is True, we need to search f1 field and if m2m_1_field if False, we need to search f2 field. How ?

Just a guess:

```
filter(Q(m2m_1_field=True, f1=val) | Q(m2m_1_field=False, f2=val)))  Is this right?
```

Please let me know for further clarification.

Comment: Create a Model Manager, based on the field boolean make the appropriate filtering.

Comment: I didn't get you. Please give example.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/managers/

Comment: You mean malemanager, femalemanager? Here, I can't call MaleManager.objecs.filter because even that boolean is part of the search.

Comment: The boolean is defined by the user? or by something else? I can't guess, you need to provide me with the flow...even with that case a Manager would be providing you the way, unless you need an instance level filter, which should become a Model method which checks the `self.booleanfield` and fetches the appropriate relation

Comment: Sorry, boolean not part of search. We donno that. But, if it is True, the search should filter(f1=value) and if it is False, filter(f2=value). Am I still not clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55467/discussion-between-user2349115-and-petkostas).

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close with your last example. I think what you want is the following:

I'm going to define what I assume your models are.

```
class M2MModel:
    pass

class ModelA:
    m2m_1_field = models.BooleanField()
    m2m_1 = models.ManyToManyField(M2MModel, related_name="m2m_1_set", null=True, blank=True)
    m2m_2 = models.ManyToManyField(M2MModel, related_name="m2m_2_set", null=True, blank=True)
```

In order to return the correct set of M2MModels back, you'd want to perform the query on `M2MModel` rather than `ModelA`.

```
model_a_id = SOME_ID_VALUE
results = M2MModel.objects.filter(
    Q(m2m_1_set__id=model_a_id, m2m_1_set__m2m_1_field=True)
    | Q(m2m_2_set__id=model_a_id, m2m_2_set__m2m_1_field=False)
).distinct()
```